# How to find element on page with text which is dynamically changed using web driver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I'm looking for way to find element which contain some exactly text, the problem is this text dynamically changes every time.
It looks like this:

```html
<div class="some class" ng-class="{ 'ngSorted': !col.noSortVisible90 }">
 <span ng-call-text class="ngbinding" style="cursor: defaulte;">some text and digits</span>
```

Where "some text and digits" element that I need.
Could somebody help me with this?

UPD: I have a lot elements with the same classes on page and also I know text phrase thet should be fount, I can provide this text to my code as parameter.

Comment: What language are you using? You haven't specified one.

Comment: I'm using Python. Sorry, I will add it to tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `id` attribute

```
<span ng-call-text id="snarfblat" class="ngbinding" style="cursor: defaulte;">some text and digits</span>
```

so you can access it within JavaScript with

```
document.getElementById("snarfblat");
```

Comment: There is no id "snarfblat" i my code) Anyway I have a lot of elements with the same slasses on page, so i lookin for exactly text.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Xpath or CSSSelector to reach to your target element, maybe on of its parent has a unique Id or a property, start from there and reach you destination i.e the concerned HTML tag with dynamic text